# Entity Framwork:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

In my project I use Entity Framework with MySQL.
this code:

```
objectContext.users.Include("posts").Take(2).ToList()
```

throws an exception: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key`

with such stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +12670485
   MySql.Data.Entity.Scope.GetFragment(String name) +27
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.AddDefaultColumns(Scope scope) +177
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.Wrap(Scope scope) +90
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.WrapJoinInputIfNecessary(InputFragment fragment, Boolean isRightPart) +251
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.HandleJoinExpression(DbExpressionBinding left, DbExpressionBinding right, DbExpressionKind joinType, DbExpression joinCondition) +110
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbJoinExpression expression) +33
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +50
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +19
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +45
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +50
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +19
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbSortExpression expression) +61
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +50
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +19
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +45
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree) +73
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +401
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +608
```

It is interesting that `objectContext.users.Take(2).ToList()` or `objectContext.users.Include("posts").ToList()` works fine.

Anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Exactly the same problem. I confirm that the `take` in the presence of a `join` seems to be the problem. In my case, since I'm projecting the EF query onto an object, doing the `take` directly on the DB as opposed to locally after the projection (the equivalente of your `objectContext.users.Include("posts").ToList()`, makes a huge difference in terms of elapsed time and memory consumed.